# Getting error while i run command docker-compose up in django python

Tags: python, django, docker

When i run the command, docker-compose up in my django python project i am getting this error, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue, any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance

```
Starting trialriskincident-backend_app_1 ... 
Starting trialriskincident-backend_db_1  ... error

ERROR: for trialriskincident-backend_db_1  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint trialriskincident-backStarting trialriskincident-backend_app_1 ... error
eady in use

ERROR: for trialriskincident-backend_app_1  Cannot start service app: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/trialriskincident-backend': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint trialriskincident-backend_db_1 (8966683c6b381483c0513fef57b5d3c3e3f0e8331cb4153d37ac5302d5c9f837): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: error while creating mount source path '/var/www/trialriskincident-backend': mkdir /var/www: read-only file system
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

# Services
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '12345678'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - ./db-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python-dev \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./ /app
```

Comment: Are you going to share your `docker-compose.yaml` and iff available your `Dockerfile`(s)?

Comment: @KlausD. i have added that in my question

Comment: Is there a local MySQL server or another MySQL container running on your system?

Comment: Yes i have workbench installed in my local server